# In tensorflow, can I construct multiple times a graph and automatically reuse the same variables in all the graphs?

Tags: variables, session, tensorflow

I might be wrong, but it’s my understanding that as long as I’m using the same session, it doesn’t matter how many times I build a graph, the variables will be the same, so if I train them for one graph, the next time within the same session I build the graph, the variables will already be trained. Am I wrong? Perhaps I need to use scopes? Or do I need to manually copy the variables between graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.make_template()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_template) may be what you are looking for. It wraps a provided set of tensor operations so that it does variable sharing.

Comment: Just to be clear, TensorFlow won't reuse variables among graph builds unless I ask for it, right?